# How to sort associative array depending on linear array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, one is linear array indicates sorted list that will be followed to sort and another is associative array that will be sorted.

Here, `$recommended_props` is sorted list and `$prop_array` is the associative that I want to sort depending on *sorted list*. Sorted list indicate the property code and I want to sort my array based on this *code* index.

**My arrays are**

```
//Sorted list of property codes
$recommended_props = [29822, 24785, 45875, 45872];

//Property details and this array will be sorted
$prop_array = [
    [
        'code' => 24785,
        'price' => 120,
        'currency' => 'USD',
    ],
    [
        'code' => 29822,
        'price' => 150,
        'currency' => 'USD',
    ],
    [
        'code' => 45872,
        'price' => 300,
        'currency' => 'USD',
    ],
    [
        'code' => 45875,
        'price' => 250,
        'currency' => 'USD',
    ],
];
```

**And my desired output is:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [code] => 29822
            [price] => 150
            [currency] => USD
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [code] => 24785
            [price] => 120
            [currency] => USD
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [code] => 45875
            [price] => 250
            [currency] => USD
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [code] => 45872
            [price] => 300
            [currency] => USD
        )

    )
```

I have done this task using loop but my curiosity is to know that have there any easy way to do this job?

**My codes what I used:**

```
$sorted_prop = [];
foreach($recommended_props as $code){
    foreach($prop_array as $key=>$property){
        if($property['code'] == $code){
            $sorted_prop[] = $property;
            unset($prop_array[$key]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) is the function to use:

```
$recommended_props = [29822, 24785, 45875, 45872];

$prop_array = [
    [
        'code' => 24785,
        'price' => 120,
        'currency' => 'USD',
    ],
    [
        'code' => 29822,
        'price' => 150,
        'currency' => 'USD',
    ],
    [
        'code' => 45872,
        'price' => 300,
        'currency' => 'USD',
    ],
    [
        'code' => 45875,
        'price' => 250,
        'currency' => 'USD',
    ],
];

usort(
    $prop_array, 
    function($a, $b) use ($recommended_props) {
        return (array_search($a['code'], $recommended_props) < array_search($b['code'], $recommended_props)) ? -1 : 1;

    }
);

var_dump($prop_array);
```

You could probably make it more efficient flipping `$recommended_props`, and using it for access via the key in the callback

Comment: Thanks @Mark Baker. I was expecting something like this solution.

Answer (score 0):

`usort` is what you need!

```
$recommended_props = [29822, 24785, 45875, 45872];

usort($prop_array, function($a, $b) use $recommended_props {
  return strpos($recommended_props, $a['code']) > strpos($recommended_props, $b['code']);
});
```

The code has not been tested but it should give you a good idea on how to proceed. (Note that you may also need to handle the case where the code is not in the $recommended_props array

Comment: Why do you need the `cmp()` function?

Comment: And `$recommended_props` is an array